# ASA database when moved/copied data dissapears

Tags: database, sybase-asa

Good Day.

I'm having a funny scenario when when I relocate a ASA database file then data goes missing. I run a PB9 application connecting to a ASA8 database via ODBC. The database contans approx 30 tables. Below are 2 actual scenario's:

1. I create a db file for a customer. I populate the database (via the app) with specific customer setup data (ABC). I then install the app and database on the customers machine. After a week the customer has added some extra data (XYZ). He then has a problem with something. I ask him to zip up the db file and email it to me. On my side I reinstate his database and find only dataset ABC. XYZ gone. I'm 100% sure I'm not confusing the old and new db files.
2. Similar scenario as above... except that I relocate his db file remotely via TeamViewer from folder A to folder B on the same machine. Upon reconnection (ODBC) to the relocated db, only data ABC exsits. XYZ is gone.

Both instances the connection to the db is made via default login dba/sql.

Anyone know whats going on or where to look to resolve this?

Thanks and kind regards
Alex

Comment: Sounds like data updates/inserts aren't persisted to the database. Is a transaction log configured when starting up the database?

Comment: My default transaction object is SQLCA and after all updates I use COMMIT; when closing a window. 
Yes there is a transaction log - how do I view it ? 
When I open it, it shows:    ÐA   ì          ^ºzÚ)           D±Û Àú

Comment: Please note that it's only when the database file is relocated to a different location. However my dataset ABC arrives well on the customer's site..